# Second order derivative

Tags: derivatives

$f(x) = \sqrt[3]{1+ \sqrt[3]x}$

I have to derive in 1st order and 2nd order

$f'(x) = \frac{1}{9x^\frac 23(1+x^\frac 13)^\frac 23}$ Is what I get after the first derivation

Now the teachers assistant is making $some$ $magic$ by showing  that

$f(u) = \frac{1}{U^\frac 23}$

$u=g(x)=x(1+{x^\frac 13}) = x + x^\frac 43$ <- where did she get that first $x$ from. For me it doesn't make sense since she got the $\frac{1}{9x^\frac 23}$ as  $u$  already so the $x$ goes there.

$f"(x)= \frac{1}{9} * f'(u) * g'(x)$ <- is how the second derivation continues. Can someone please explain how you would get a second order derivative?

Is there some kind of rule am I missing or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed,

$$\left(\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt[3]x}\right)'=\frac13{x^{-2/3}}\frac13\left({1+\sqrt[3]x}\right)^{-2/3}=\frac19(x(1+\sqrt[3]x))^{-2/3}=\frac19(x+x^{4/3})^{-2/3}.$$

Then by the chain rule (with $u:=x+x^{4/3}$),

$$\left(\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt[3]x}\right)''=\left(\frac19u^{-2/3}\right)'=-\frac23u'\frac19u^{-5/3}=-\frac2{27}\frac{1+\frac43\sqrt[3]x}{x^{5/3}(1+\sqrt[3]x)^{5/3}}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I clearly didn't get the first part of the brackets correctly. Amazing, now I don't feel like I have wasted 2 hours of my life for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

> $u=g(x)=x(1+{x^\frac 13}) = x + x^\frac 43$ <- where did she get that first $x$ from. For me it doesn't make sense since she got the $\frac{1}{9x^\frac 23}$ as  $u$  already so the $x$ goes there.

It is not the $\frac{1}{9x^\frac 23}$ which is $u$. The factor 9 seems to be omitted, but that's just a constant factor you leave hanging. The assistent defines $u=g(x)$ as $\color{blue}{g(x)=x(1+{x^\frac 13})}$ so notice then that you have:
$$u^\tfrac{2}{3} = \color{blue}{g(x)}^\tfrac{2}{3}= \color{blue}{x(1+{x^\frac 13})}^\tfrac{2}{3} = \color{red}{x^\tfrac{2}{3}(1+{x^\frac 13})^\tfrac{2}{3}}$$
And that's exactly what you have in the denominator of $f'(x)$, apart from the extra factor 9:

> $f'(x) = \frac{1}{9\color{red}{x^\frac 23(1+x^\frac 13)^\frac 23}}$ Is what I get after the first derivation

Or the other way around by using $a^\tfrac{2}{3}b^\tfrac{2}{3}=(ab)^\tfrac{2}{3}$, rewrite as follows and introduce $u$:

$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{9{x^\frac 23(1+x^\frac 13)^\frac 23}} 
=  \frac{1}{9{\left(\color{blue}{ x(1+x^\frac 13)}\right)^\frac 23}}=\frac{1}{9{\color{blue}{u}^\frac 23}}$$
with again $\color{blue}{u=g(x)=x(1+{x^\frac 13})}$.

The idea behind this, is to simplify finding the second derivative by use of the chain rule.

---

We have with $u=x(1+{x^\frac 13})=x+x^\frac 43$:
$$f(x) =  \sqrt[3]{1+ \sqrt[3]x} \implies f'(x) = \frac{1}{9x^\tfrac{2}{3}\left(1+x^\tfrac{1}{3} \right)^\tfrac{2}{3}}= \frac{1}{9u^\tfrac{2}{3}}$$
Then by the chain rule:
$$f''(x) = \frac{\mbox{d}}{\mbox{d}x}f'(u(x)) = \frac{\mbox{d}}{\mbox{d}u}f'(u) \frac{\mbox{d}u}{\mbox{d}x}$$

Comment: The more I look at this problem the dumber I get. I think I have missed some vital part of derivatives. The substitution just confuses me so much. I need private teacher help or something.

Comment: There is a very confusing part: the assistent uses the name $f$ again to define $f(u)$, but that's in fact $f'(u)$ with the initial $f$ and the chosen intermediate function $u=g(x)$.